# Is it appropriate to provide editorial oversight for a paper authored by someone who plans to move to your institution?

Tags: journals, ethics, editors, conflict-of-interest

I see some journal editors handle the papers authored by their colleagues. It is usually not allowed to handle papers authored by colleagues in the same institution. After a deeper check of one paper, I find that in the initial submission date the author was not affiliate with the new institution, but they accepted the offer to move to that new institution next year.

After moving, the author and the editor become colleagues. I wonder if this is considered a "conflict of interests".

Answer (score 1):

In my field, most papers would already be accepted or long since rejected by the 1 year mark. So in this case a conflict of interest is very unlikely since the paper would have been accepted before they two became colleagues in any meaningful sense.

But, since you are asking the question, I'm going to assume that papers take longer to publish in whatever field you're in. In that case, the answer is an unsatisfying *maybe*. As an editor I would be concerned about a potential conflict of interest. I would hope that any competent editor would consider it too. There are lots of variables and moving parts that make it hard to cleanly determine though. It is best to avoid editors handling submissions from their own institutions, but I think that exceptions can be made. I would really only be worried if there is a pattern of similar instances or if there is something else concerning.